# PySpark Reduce using UnionByName with Arguments

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

```
output = reduce(lambda x,y: x.unionByName(y, allowMissingColumns=True), list_of_dfs)
```

I want to effectively perform a unionAll on a list of dataframes that have inconsistent columns. I had previously used a gross for-loop, but started doing the above; as it turns out it's only mildly more efficient. Is there a more efficient way to do this? Before, I had used

```
output = reduce(Dataframe.unionByName, list_of_dfs)
```

however this does not allow me to allow missing columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a partial (from functools)

```
union_partial = partial(DataFrame.unionByName, allowMissingColumns=True)
output = reduce(union_partial, list_of_dfs)
```